# unity Facebook log in issue android

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Trying to integrate facebook SDK (5.0.3) with unity 4.3.4f1, the Facebook plugin is the only one used with demo scene that was imported with the package, after ruining demo "Interactive Console" on galaxy S3 I get the following in the logcat when I try to log in.

```
03-23 17:25:49.394: V/FBUnitySDK(25474): sending to Unity OnLoginComplete({"cancelled":true,"key_hash":"lRqLQiGMJz7jRGI5FfmBqfevJUk=\n"})
```

The keyhash was different from the one in the Facebook settings , i copied it to my app setting on the Facebook developer page, but still got the same error, is this error related to the keyhash or to the activity callback, and how do I solve it?

**UPDATE**: logging in works from the same developer account, therefore it must be a keyhash issue , please let me know how to get the right keyhash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case someone wondering what i did wrong, you need to expose your app to the public via Facebook developer page under status & review in order to be able to test with normal users

Answer (score 0):

You can Access it by going to the Menu - > Facebook -> Edit Setting
[image]

You can test the a sample app that i have created... here https://github.com/casterfile/Unity-Facebook-Soscial-Share

you just need to change the APP ID and Copy the info below Android Build Facebook Setting... Cheers.